# NodeJS - Cookie dissapears for a moment on refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, cookies, session-cookies

I have this problem with my authentication that only happens upon refresh. My authentication middleware looks like this:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require('express');

const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const {cookies} = req;
    if ('token' in cookies) {
        jwt.verify(cookies.token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('COOKIE ERROR')
                res.redirect('/../notLoggedIn');
            }
            req.userId = decoded.user_id;
            next();
        });
    } else {
        console.log('NO VALID TOKEN')
        res.redirect('/../notLoggedIn');
    }
}


module.exports = verifyToken;
```

It works perfectly when going into routes, but if I'm already in an authRoute, for example "profile", and refresh the page, I will get the console.log "NO VALID TOKEN". But then when I check the cookies I can see that it is there. My only conclusion is that the cookie dissapears for a split second when refreshing and the authentication middleware is fired before the cookie comes back.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Ps. My setup for the sessioncookies looks like this:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000*60*30,
        //secure: true, //Only have true when deploying on https
        sameSite: true
    },
    rolling: true,
    httpOnly: true,
}));
```

I have tried with multiple configurations but still can't get it to work.

Edit:

Here is where I set the cookie on login

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    await db.query(
    'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], 
    (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send({err: err});
        }

        if (result.length > 0) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

            bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password, (error, response) => {
                if (response) {
                    const user_id = result[0].id;
                    const email = result[0].email;
                    data = {
                        user_id,
                        email
                    }
                    jwt.sign(data, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, accessToken) => {
                        if(err){
                            res.send(err)
                        } else {
                            res.cookie('token', accessToken, {httpOnly: true, secret: process.env.SECRET, sameSite: true, maxAge: date}); //Set secure: true when deploying
                            res.send({auth: true})
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    res.json({message: 'Wrong email/password combination', auth: false,});
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.send({message: 'User does not exist!', auth: false,});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `maxAge` property in the session should just have `1000*60*30` instead of `Date.now() + 1000*60*30`.

[Link to the express-session documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)

Comment: That was what I had initially and it doesn't work either, I changed it to Date.now() because I read on some other thread that it could work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to share a snippet code that contains a set cookie logic.
It might be the problem

Comment: Will do, give me a minute!

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I have updated the post with a snippet from my login route

Comment: @ThomasHirsch you're right my friend ^^,  but I can't write a comment because of my reputation

Comment: depending on the given information there should be no problems.
if you can share the whole project that would be better so we can debug it.

Comment: Sure, just give me some time to create a repo